# defining and looping through arrays tcl

Tags: tcl

I need some help in defining arrays and displaying and looping thrrough them in TCL.

Here is how I would do them in php.

```
$date =array();
$size=0;
$date[$size] =$pre_event_date;
/* After doing some manpulation and calculations with $size */
for($i=0;$i<=$size;$i++){
    echo $date[$i];
}
```

I would like to do the same with tcl.Is the following code appropriate?

```
set size 0
set date[$size] $pre_event_date
#After performing some manipulation
for {set i 0} { $i <=$size } {incr i} {
    puts "$date[$i]";
}
```

Also can I define set $date as an array. Some like like:

```
set date array();
```

So i edited my code tried a simple test using RSeeger's array implementation:

```
set date(0) 35
set date(1)  40
foreach key [array names date]{
   puts "${key}=$date($key)"
}
```

the above doesnt return anything there is probably some error.
I also tried:
puts $date($key) without quotes but that doesnt work either.

Comment: You would benefit from the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Comment: The problem with your last code snippet is that it lacks a space between the `[array names date]` and the `{`. That space is **significant** in Tcl! It separates the thing being iterated over (the serialized array contents) from the script to execute for each iteration. In general, with Tcl you _must_ separate your words properly; it rapidly becomes second nature (and I tend to do the identical thing now in many other languages too, as extra whitespace boosts readability nearly everywhere, provided it is semantically legal).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking to index things by number (which your code implies), use a `list`. It is analogous to an array in C.

```
set mylist {}
lappend mylist a
lappend mylist b
lappend mylist c
lappend mylist d
foreach elem $mylist {
    puts $elem
}
// or if you really want to use for
for {set i 0} {$i < [length $mylist]} {incr i} {
    puts "${i}=[lindex $mylist $i]"
}
```

If you want to index things by string (or have a sparse list), you can use an `array`, which is a hashmap of key->value.

```
set myarr(chicken) animal
set myarr(cows) animal
set myarr(rock) mineral
set myarr(pea) vegetable

foreach key [array names myarr] {
    puts "${key}=$myarr($key)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RHSeeger. I tried one of your methods but it doesnt work. see my edits above

Comment: I still think you'd be better off using lists and not arrays.

Comment: @user856753, also note that Tcl arrays might feel inconvenient to programmers coming from other langugages in that they themselves *are not values,* so you can't pass arrays into procs and return them; you can only pass around names of arrays.  Since the release 8.5 Tcl has [`dict`ionaries](http://wiki.tcl.tk/dict) which are first-class values. So if you need a hashmap and can use Tcl 8.5+, look at the `dict` command.

Comment: I'm not an expert in tcl scripting but isn't it `for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $mylist]} {incr i} {` instead of `for {set i 0} {$i < [length $mylist]} {incr i} {` ? ( **length** > **llength** )

Answer (score 6):

In Tcl, array concept differs from many other programming languages and what Tcl calls an array is often called hash map or associative array elsewhere. Array indices are not limited to integers but can be any legal strings. Most of the time I find myself using lists (or lists of lists) instead of arrays for data manipulation. For looping through a whole list or an array you can use command foreach.

```
foreach {index content} [array get date] {
    put $index: $content
}
```

You don't have to initialize the array before setting it's values, just start adding the members. Individual array members are referenced as

```
 $array($key) or $array("abc")
```

There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Tcl, but they can be simulated by having consistent key names, for example

```
set a(1,1) 0
set a(1,2) 1
...
```

Other than that, I would just point you to mostly excellent Tcl wiki and it's [array page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1032) and [array man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/array.htm) for syntax issues as I don't see point repeating most of their content here.

Comment: You can do multidimensional structures by nesting lists; `lindex` and `lset` have multi-index forms specifically for this case. For cases where you need that sort of thing, it works well (and its fast too).

Answer (score 3):

TCL arrays are closer to what Python calls a dict, and a hash in Perl.
So it helps to think of the index as a keystring, rather than a index integer:

```
set groceries(fruit) "banana"
set groceries(1) "banana"
```

You can use the [array](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/array.htm) function to do useful things, like generate a list
of all keys, and you can iterate through that list if you need to. 
For example, you could generate a list of keys and then use [llength](http://www.hume.com/html85/mann/llength.html) to get the array size.

This works best if you need a unique index to find them.
If you just need an ordered list- than you might be better off using actual list functions like [lappend](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm).

Comment: so i guess i ll to have do it in a slightly different way than the way I wrote my code above..

Comment: As Edu mentioned - foreach is really nice for working with lists, there is a good chance it could make your life easier if lists are suitable for solving your problem.

Comment: well in this case I need arrays similar to the code mentioned above..I dont see lists suitable for me in my current situation..

Comment: Depends on the contents of $pre_event_date - maybe you could use the 'split' command.  Populating the actual list or array seems to be the part that will determine what works best for you - but since you are using just a counter as an index, I would make sure you check out llindex before deciding.